# Browse and retrieve a Facebook gallery photo

Tags: facebook, api, gallery

Hmm - a complete working generic HTML page that allows a user to login to Facebook account, browse their galleries and select a photo - the URL of which should then be stored in a javascript variable?

Answer (score 0):

This hits the nail on the head!

https://github.com/davellx/jQuery-GetFacebookAlbums

Enjoy!